# Copy all data from selected source workbook sheet to destination workbook sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to copy data from a source file sheet to destination file sheet. Destination file sheet contains the macro. But I keep getting error in selecting the range of data in source sheet file. Can someone please help correct my error for this line?
 *Set srcData = sourceSht.Range(StartCell & ":" & sourceSht.Cells(lRow, lCol)).Select*

```
    ' Open file
        wbkName = ThisWorkbook.Name ' this workbook is the macro workbook file
        filePath = Sheet29.Range("D2").Value 'this contains filepath of source workbook
        Set sourceSht = Sheet29.Range("C12") ' this contains name of sheet of source workbook
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

    ' Copy source file contents
        Set StartCell = sourceSht.Range("A1")
        lRow = sourceSht.Cells(sourceSht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row 'select last row value

        lCol = sourceSht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sourceSht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'select last column value

        Set srcData = sourceSht.Range(StartCell & ":" & sourceSht.Cells(lRow, lCol)).Select
        srcData.Copy

'Paste data to destination macro sheet
wbkName.Active
Sheets("CopyMacro").Range("E14").Value
srcData.paste
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While setting the range, you don't need to `Select` it.

You must remove `.Select` from the following line...

```
Set srcData = sourceSht.Range(StartCell & ":" & sourceSht.Cells(lRow, lCol)).Select
```

And also you may set the range like below...

```
Set srcData = sourceSht.Range(StartCell, sourceSht.Cells(lRow, lCol))
```

Then you can `copy and paste` the `srcData` without activating the `wbkName` workbook like below...

```
srcData.Copy wbkName.Sheets("CopyMacro").Range("E14")
```

Comment: There are few steps I am performing before pasting the data, like clearing old data and formatting. So when I do srcData.paste later but it shows error 438 "Object doesnt follow property or method". Can you help?

Comment: `srcData` is the `range` which you are copying and if you want to `paste` the copied range, you must try something like `Sheets("CopyMacro").Range("E14").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

Comment: It's throwing Error number 1004, pastespecial method of range class failed.

Comment: It should work. I don't see any issue with the code suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The default property of a range is `.Value` so when you say `.Range(StartCell & ":"...` you are not addressing the cell address but it's value. Try this

```
Set srcData = sourceSht.Range(startCell.Address & ":" & sourceSht.Cells(lRow, lCol).Address)
```

And then you can use that range as

```
With srcData
    '~~> Do what you want
End With
```

BTW your code can also be written as

```
Set srcData = sourceSht.Range("A1:" & Cells(lRow, lCol).Address)

With srcData
    .Copy
    wbkName.Sheets("CopyMacro").Range("E14").PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
```

Notice we use `Cells(lRow, lCol).Address` and not `sourceSht.Cells(lRow, lCol).Address`. There is no need because the address will be the same across worksheets. It will return a String. For example `Set srcData = sourceSht.Range("A1:" & "$C$10")`

Comment: This worked. But I am facing issues pasting copied data. There are few steps I am performing before pasting the data, like clearing old data and formatting. So when I do srcData.paste it shows error 438 "Object doesnt follow property or method". Can you help?

Comment: So I guess your probem is sorted?

Comment: No. Still getting error number 1004, pastespecial method of range class failed for the particular paste code.

Comment: Probably becuase you are not immediatley copying and pasting. Excel has an uncanny habit of clearing the clipboard.  I have updated the above post to demonstrate how to copy paste

Comment: Also it is advisable to work with `Objects` instead of using `Activesheet/ActiveWorkbook/.Select/Selection` etc...